# Websocket: Many users drag one item at the same time

Tags: jquery, websocket, drag-and-drop, draggable, drag

I'm using jquery drag, drop with websocket. When user drag drop item, it will automatically update on other user screens. Like this video: https://youtu.be/JHndS1ps_f0

I want when user dragging member, other user cannot drag that member. This is my code:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws');
var id_user = $(".id_user").attr('data-id');
    $(".item").draggable({
        revert: true,
        revertDuration: 0,
        drag: function( event, ui ) {
            var team_id_previous = $(this).attr('data-id-team');
            var member_id = $(this).attr('data-id-member');
            // Send to server
            socket.send(
                JSON.stringify({
                    team_id_previous: team_id_previous,
                    member_id: member_id,
                    user_id: id_user,
                    type: "drag"
                })
            );
        }
    });
```

Listen msg from server:

```
socket.onmessage = function (e) {
        var msg = JSON.parse(e.data);
        var item = $("[data-id-member=" + msg.member_id + "][data-id-team=" + msg.team_id_previous + "]");
        if (msg.type === "drag" && msg.user_id != id_user) {
            item.draggable('disable');
            item.css("background-color", "gainsboro");
        }
};
```

It's ok if i drag in turn, drag at this screen, then drag at another screen, it will be disabled. But, when many people drag one member at the sametime, latency is almost = 0, then both can drag. What can I do to solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have the server arbitrate by remembering the dragger-in-charge for each draggable. When you get a drag message, check if anyone else is dragging it by consulting the dragger-in-charge map; if it's someone other than the current user, send back a cancel message (which should undo the drag attempt), otherwise broadcast the drag. Additionally, if there's no dragger-in-charge for the relevant draggable, enter the current user (socket ID) as the dragger-in-charge for it. When drag stops (or you get a disconnect), delete the relevant dragger-in-charge entry.